CocoaPods pod init Fails with “Unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup” Error on Xcode 16
I’m trying to initialize CocoaPods in a new iOS project using Xcode 16. When I run pod init, I get the following error:
RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup`


I’ve updated CocoaPods, Xcode, and xcodeproj, but the error still persists. Has anyone else encountered this issue with Xcode 16, and how did you resolve it?
Environment:
•   Xcode 16.0
•   CocoaPods: 1.15.2
•   macOS 15.0

Command
/usr/local/bin/pod init

Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin24]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 15.0 (24A5331b)
       Xcode : 16.0 (16A242)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/

Error
RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup` from attributes: `{"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", "exceptions"=>["AE97BCA32C917722000D94D0"], "path"=>"tesPlayer", "sourceTree"=>"<group>"}`
If this ISA was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new


I am facing same issue in iOS 18.0 and XCode 16
Note: Before this step try
@zhaozhang solution if it not resolved problem
Then
Try this step by step it will be resolved.

Close XCode
Go to your project folder remove Pods & Podfile.lock
Right Click on YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj Show Package Contents then open project.pbxproj
Replace every PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup with PBXGroup
Search for objectVersion should be like that objectVersion = 56; if not replace by 56
Pod install

Enjoy:)

The @zhaozhang solution works!

In Xcode, right-click on the folder, select Convert to Group from the context menu, and then it can be used normally.


Thanks! As a not for anyone else: If this was done in the past, select Convert To Folder first, then select Convert To Group.

Thanks! I just ran into this issue too, and turns out it was because I had created folders and not groups inside my project. Awesome...

Here the solution that worked for me: right click projectname.xcodeproj file and select Show Package Contents you can see the file project.pbxproj and open with texteditor Remove the following lines in this file minimizedProjectReferenceProxies = 1; preferredProjectObjectVersion = 77; Also update the below version objectVersion = 77; to objectVersion = 56;
from this post: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12583


Go to the ios/YOUR_APP_NAME folder.xcodeproj in finder
Right click, select "show package contents"
Open the project.pbxproj file
Autocorrect change PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup to PBX Group
Save the file, it works


sorry not so expert can be more details? I mean when I open my project and click on my xcodeproj file it just open Xcode, where I found this PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup thanks a lot

@damiano-miazzi you need to open it not in XCode, but in the code editor

sorry I managed to open the project.pbcproj with code editor but I can't find PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup

untimeError

PBXGroup attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup from attributes: {"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", "path"=>"SkyTrackTests", "sourceTree"=>""}

I got this error and I resolved this by replacing PBXGroup with PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup in project.pbxproj file. To go on this file, first of all you need to right click on your projectname.xcodeproject file, then a window will come with show content, click on it and there you will find project.pbxproj file. Now open it in Xcode or Visual Studio Code, and make changes as mentioned above. And then you will be good to go.

In Xcode, right-click on the your project name folder and select Convert to Group. This will solve the pod init issue. To run pod install and successfully install the pods, you will have to change the Xcode project version as indicated by the pod install command in the terminal.  Xcode project version (77) is higher than the latest supported by xcodeproj (63). To change this, go to you project directory, right click on YOUR_PROJECT.xcodeproj and click who package content. Open project.pbxpro file in editor and change the object version 77 to the one mentioned in your terminal.

It helped me:

You should convert to group folders of targets (right click on folder -> convert to group; if already aconverted you should see "converted to folder")
Open project.pbxproj - remove this lines: minimizedProjectReferenceProxies = 1; preferredProjectObjectVersion = 77;
Change objectVersion to 56

