I keep getting a Pod install error in terminal
I'm trying to use the google maps SDK api for an xcode (version 16.0) project, I downloaded Ruby 3.1.0 using Rbenv, and I have Cocoapods (1.15.2) downloaded. I verified that I'm using Ruby 3.1.0 by running the command:
ruby -v 

which gave me:
ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) \[arm64-darwin24\] 

I verified the contents by running the command:
nano Podfile 

which returned:
platform :ios, '18.0.1'
use_frameworks!

target 'project' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GoogleMapsUtils'
end

I ran a which pod command:
which pod 

which returned:
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/shims/pod

I confirmed the command:
gem install cocoapods

which returned:
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.15.2
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.15.2
Done installing documentation for cocoapods after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

However,  when I try running pod install it says (note: replaced username with 'redacted'):
### Command

/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/pod install

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [arm64-darwin24]
    RubyGems : 3.3.3
        Host : macOS 15.0 (24A335)
       Xcode : 16.0 (16A242d)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-154)
Ruby lib dir : /Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib
Repositories : cocoapods - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 552a3ae78b414762bd2fa760bd66c469ad9688bf

### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0

### Podfile

platform :ios, '18.0.1'
use_frameworks!

target 'project' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
    pod 'GoogleMapsUtils'
end

### Error

RuntimeError - `PBXGroup` attempted to initialize an object with unknown ISA `PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup` from attributes: `{"isa"=>"PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup", "path"=>"project", "sourceTree"=>"<group>"}`
If this ISA was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:359:in `rescue in object_with_uuid'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:349:in `object_with_uuid'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:290:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `each'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:287:in `configure_with_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:272:in `new_from_plist'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:213:in `initialize_from_file'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.25.1/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1194:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/Users/redacted/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%60PBXGroup%60+attempted+to+initialize+an+object+with+unknown+ISA+%60PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup%60+from+attributes%3A+%60%7B%22isa%22%3D%3E%22PBXFileSystemSynchronizedRootGroup%22%2C+%22path%22%3D%3E%project%22%2C+%22sourceTree%22%3D%3E%22%3Cgroup%3E%22%7D%60%0AIf+this+ISA+was+generated+by+Xcode+please+file+an+issue%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCocoaPods%2FXcodeproj%2Fissues%2Fnew&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

      report.issues = results['items'].map { |item| Issue.new(item) }
                                      ^^^^

I tried deleting the pod and recreating a new one and nothing is working. Apologies for any inaccuracies in terminology, I'm new to this/trying to understand what's going on.
I tried deleting the pod several times and rewriting the lines/saving them but it didn't work.

This error is discussed at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/12456. Please scroll through it; eventually we come to a section that discusses possible solutions.

Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78984326/cocoapods-pod-init-fails-with-unknown-isa-pbxfilesystemsynchronizedrootgroup-e

Also see my https://stackoverflow.com/a/79044632/341994 for an explanation of the change in Xcode that has caused this issue.

@matt Thank you for the explanation, I was able to get it working. However it stated this also stated in the terminal: [!] [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes.... Could you please elaborate on what that means?
